# Bigquery Google Analytics Users Not Counting Unique

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm having issues with the below query in BigQuery for Google Analytics. For some reason I'm not able to count the number of users as unique, it essentially counts the number of rows so the numbers are very similar to sessions. I've also tried EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT() but gives me the same answer.

```
    SELECT
  date AS Day,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId CONTAINS '778****' THEN 'MUG'
      WHEN hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId = 'Social' THEN 'Social'ELSE 'Website' END) AS Property,
  geoNetwork.country AS Country,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS visits,
  COUNT (DISTINCT(fullVisitorId), 1000000) AS Users,
  SUM(IFNULL(totals.newVisits,0)) AS NEW,
  (SUM(IFNULL(totals.screenviews,0))+SUM(IFNULL(totals.pageviews,0))) AS PAGEVIEWS,
  IFNULL(SUM(CASE
        WHEN totals.screenviews = 1 THEN SUM(IFNULL(totals.screenviews,0))
        ELSE 0 END)+ SUM(IFNULL(totals.bounces,0)),0) AS BOUNCES,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.eventInfo.eventAction,'register$|registersuccess|new registration|account signup|registro') THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS NewRegistrations,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.eventInfo.eventAction, 'add to cart|add to bag|click to buy|ass to basket|comprar') OR hits.eventInfo.eventAction CONTAINS 'addtobasket::' THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS ClickToBuy,
  SUM(IFNULL(totals.transactions,0)) AS Transactions,
  SUM(IFNULL(totals.transactionRevenue,0))/1000000 AS Revenue
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([****.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-03-15'), TIMESTAMP('2017-03-31'))),
GROUP BY
  Day,
  Country,
  geoNetwork.country,
  totals.screenviews;
```

Comment: Why are you grouping by `screenviews`?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard This, i think, is the problem. I try to leave it out but it keeps forcing me to

Comment: I think the problem is that you have some nested aggregations, i.e. SUM within a SUM. If you fix that logic, the query should work. I would really recommend using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) for your analysis, though. You might also be interested in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: thanks @elliot, will give it a go. Would the subqueries within selects be the biggest advantage here?

Comment: A couple of others are that `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` gives exact results (and is generally faster than `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT`), and that repeated field handling related to `ga_sessions_` tables is a lot saner, though you may find that there is a learning curve. The [Working with Arrays topic](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) is a good introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this query and it seems a bit simpler:

```
SELECT
date,
MAX(CASE
     WHEN hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId CONTAINS '778****' THEN 'MUG'
     WHEN hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId = 'Social' THEN 'Social'ELSE 'Website' END) AS Property,
geoNetwork.country AS Country,
SUM(totals.visits) AS visits,
COUNT(DISTINCT(fullVisitorId), 1000000) AS Users,
SUM(totals.newVisits) AS NEW,
SUM(totals.pageviews) AS PAGEVIEWS,
SUM(totals.bounces) AS BOUNCES,
SUM(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.eventInfo.eventAction,'register$|registersuccess|new registration|account signup|registro') THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS NewRegistrations,
SUM(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(hits.eventInfo.eventAction, 'add to cart|add to bag|click to buy|ass to basket|comprar|addtobasket::') THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS ClickToBuy,
SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions,
SUM(totals.transactionRevenue) /1000000 AS Revenue
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project_id:dataset_id.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-03-15'), TIMESTAMP('2017-03-31'))),
GROUP BY
date, Country
```

It did work in our database (not sure why you summed *screenviews* with *pageviews* though).

In Standard SQL (highly recommended that you use this version) maybe this already solves for you:

```
SELECT
date,
MAX(CASE
     WHEN exists(select 1 from unnest(hits) hits where regexp_contains(hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId, r'778\*\*\*\*')) THEN 'MUG'
     WHEN exists(select 1 from unnest(hits) hits where hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId = 'Social') THEN 'Social'ELSE 'Website' END) AS Property,
geoNetwork.country AS Country,
SUM(totals.visits) AS visits,
COUNT(DISTINCT(fullVisitorId)) AS Users,
SUM(totals.newVisits) AS new_,
SUM(totals.pageviews) AS PAGEVIEWS,
SUM(totals.bounces) AS BOUNCES,
SUM(CASE
      WHEN exists(select 1 from unnest(hits) hits where REGEXP_contains(hits.eventInfo.eventAction,'register$|registersuccess|new registration|account signup|registro')) THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS NewRegistrations,
SUM(CASE
      WHEN exists(select 1 from unnest(hits) hits where REGEXP_contains(hits.eventInfo.eventAction, 'add to cart|add to bag|click to buy|ass to basket|comprar|addtobasket::')) THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS ClickToBuy,
SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions,
SUM(totals.transactionRevenue) /1000000 AS Revenue
FROM `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions*`
where 1 = 1
and parse_timestamp("%Y%m%d", regexp_extract(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) between  TIMESTAMP('2017-03-15') and  TIMESTAMP('2017-03-31')
GROUP BY
date, Country
```

Comment: I was combining screenviews from an app and pageviews from a website but I guess it would be easier if I just made intermediary tables! Thanks @will this works

Comment: Hi @will, trying to work with Standard SQL version. I want to add hostname, and homepage loadspeed. Would you be able to show me?

Comment: Glad to know it worked :). As for adding hostname and homepage loadspeed maybe it would be better to start a new question showing what you want to implement and tried so far as it might be more complex to solve (hits is a repeated field in ga's schema so probably it will have to be unnested which may change the query)

Comment: managed to work it out with some extensive trial and error, thanks!